# Построение предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте!
Какие ошибки я допустил в предложении: "Поступки друзей значимее их обещаний"
Слово "значимее" можно заменить на более подходящие синонимы (важнее/ценнее и т.д.), но все же хочу использовать именно его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибок не вижу.Значимее - такое слово есть в парадигме слова (по Зализняку), но я бы написала "Поступки друзей более значимы, чем  их обещания"

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предпочла глагол: "Поступки друзей значат больше, чем их обещания". А из прилагательных можно выбрать что-нибудь другое:"Поступки друзей важнее их обещаний","Поступки друзей информативнее их обещаний"  и т.д.